# wrong credentials should response with some custom message rather than redirecting to some link

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a spring security application. Its working well. When I enter wrong credentials it redirect to `spring_security_login?login_error` where it show spring default login page. What I want is if user enter wrong credentials its should response with some custom message rather than redirecting to some link.

Here is my config

```
<http auto-config="true">
    <form-login
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" />
    <csrf/>
</http>
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Did you try anything that didn't work? If so, please update your question. Maybe someone has another idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to redirect the user to a custom URL use the `authentication-failure-url` attribute of `<form-login>`:

```
<http auto-config="true">
    <form-login
        authentication-failure-url="/myCustomLoginFailureURL"
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" />
    <csrf/>
</http>
```

If you want full control over what happens on login failures, use the `authentication-failure-handler-ref` attribute:

```
<beans:bean id="authenticationFailureHandler" class="my.company.AuthenticationFailureHandler" />

<http auto-config="true">
    <form-login
        authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureHandler"
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" />
    <csrf/>
</http>
```

Note that `my.company.AuthenticationFailureHandler` needs to implement `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationFailureHandler`.